# Multiple certificate chains in a single file

Tags: certificate-authority, pki

My company has a Windows-based PKI with a single standalone root CA and several subordinate  CAs for different audiences/purposes (e.g. two subordinate CAs for user/machine auto-enrollment, an independent CA for networking equipment, another independent CA for dedicated VPNs with other companies etc.).

Is there a format that allows me to distribute the certificates for all such CAs (root and all of its subordinates) in a single file?

Is so, how can I create such file? What should be included, and in what order?

Comment: Distribute to who/where?

Comment: @garethTheRed, good point. Tried editing the question, but apparently I cannot anymore.

It mean to distribute to clients in the the company's internal networks, to whoever needs to authenticate certificates signed by any of those CAs.

For Windows clients, this is normally done with a series of certificates in a GPO. However, GPO isn't such a viable option for many non-Windows clients. It would be convient if such clients were able to download a single file containing all necessary certificates and chains.

Comment: You shouldn't need to distribute your subordinate CAs to clients. Your clients require the root CA in their trust-anchor stores, at which point they trust any certs issued by it or its subordinate CAs.  The server _must_ send all the intermediate certificates between its end-entity (leaf) certificate and the root CA as part of the TLS handshake.

Comment: Do you mean like "Include all certificates in the certification path if possible" when exporting to a pfx? That's probably not much more useful than simply providing a zip file with your CA certificates.  A decision still needs to be made to trust the root and place it in the Trusted Store.